# How can I run origen with more recent Ruby versions like 2.5/2.6?

Tags: origen-sdk

I wanted to use more recent Ruby APIs from 2.4+ but origen seems to be on 2.3.  It may be due to my installation.  I tried to set my ruby path to 2.5.  Launched standard "irb" to confirm and it is on 2.5.  But when `origen i` is launched and "RUBY_VERSION" is checked, it's stuck to 2.3.
What other steps need to be done to change ruby version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only version restriction that Origen has is > 2, so it works fine with 2.5.

If you have multiple Ruby versions available then the Origen gem would need to be installed in each one separately.

It sounds like this may be more related to your work environment, like it has an official version of origen that is registered to the 2.3 package or something similar.

Comment: Hi Ginty, Thanks for the answer.  To confirm, you're saying all I need to do is to re-install Origen and make sure that it is tied to the version that i want?

Comment: A gem is installed per Ruby version, so if you have multiple Ruby versions available then it would need to be installed to each one separately.
So if your environment is setup with Ruby 2.5, then installing Origen for that version is as simple as "gem install origen". However, in a corporate environment it may not be so simple if you don't have permission to install gems to the system Ruby, in that case your admin would need to do the install.

Comment: I'm on windows and  finally installed it to Ruby 2.5.  The only conflict there was on rake.  "rake's executable "rake" conflicts with C:/Ruby25-x64/bin/rake
Overwrite the executable? [yN]  Y
Successfully installed rake-10.5.0"  . But the installation was successful when overwrite was chosen.